# Calculation of the Minkowski-functional

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $X:=C([0,1];\mathbb{R})$ with the norm$||u||_\infty:=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|u(t)|$ be a normed space and $K:=\{u\in X\mid\int_0^1|u(t)|^2dt<1\}$
>   Calculate the Minkowski functional $p$ of $K$ and show that $p$ defines a norm on $X$. Is this norm equivalent to $||\cdot||_\infty$?

We defined the Minkowski functional by $p(x):=\inf\{\lambda>0 \mid\frac{x}{\lambda}\in K\}$ for a normed space $X$ and $K\subset X$. How do I "calculate"  the Minkowski-functional? Or is simply $p(x):=\inf\{a>0 \mid \frac{1}{a}x\in K\}$? I'm not sure how I can answer this. Can someone help me?

Comment: $\int_0^1|\frac 1a u(t)|^2dt < 1\iff\int_0^1|u(t)|^2dt < a^2 $

Comment: Do you mean: $p(u(t)):=\inf\{a>0|\int_0^1|\frac{1}{a}u(t)|^2dt<1\}$?

Comment: The expression in your comment is correct. I think what Gabriel is trying to hint at is that $\int |u|^2 $ should remind you of a norm on function spaces, and you should think about how $p$ relates to that norm.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 2):

As for calculating a Minkowski functional, one tries to find an explicit formula in order to calculate it. Let $u\not= 0$. If $a<(\int u^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ then

$$\int \bigg|\frac{u}{a}\bigg|^2>\frac{\int u^2}{\int u^2}=1,$$

that is $u/a \not\in K$, then $p(u)\ge (\int u^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. If $a> (\int u^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ then

$$\int \bigg|\frac{u}{a}\bigg|^2<\frac{\int u^2}{\int u^2}=1,$$

that is $u/a \in K$, then $p(u)\le (\int u^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Moreover $p(0)=0$, so for any $u$ we have $p(u)=(\int u^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\|u\|_{L^2}$, that is known to be a norm. However, this norm is not equivalent to $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. In fact take for example the sequence of functions $u_n$ like: $u_n(x)=-nx+1$ on $[0,1/n]$ and $0$ on $[1/n,1]$. Then $\|u_n\|_{L^2}=p(u_n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, but for all $n$ we have $\|u_n\|_\infty=1$. So there is not a constant $C$ such that $\|u_n\|_\infty\le C \|u_n\|_{L^2}$ for all $n$, that means that the two norms are not equivalent.